# Render Form partial from Ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form as image below:

[image: Form with partial]

Then I want to render this partial from ajax call: from `.js.erb`. But I don't know how to pass object to f from partial. See the image below:

how can I pass object to f:

[image: file .js.erb]

Comment: link image here: 1. https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=Screenshot+from+2016-03-05+14%3A28%3A24.png
2. https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=Screenshot+from+2016-03-05+14%3A27%3A59.png

Comment: Do you want to run it **Async** ? Or you want to pull a **form** with ajaxing ?

Comment: I want to pull form with ajaxing

Comment: Rails has own Ajax call function, making remotely by adding `remote: true`. I posted below check that one...

Comment: Let me know, if it not work...

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm trying to do the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to put just a rails form element in a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724045/is-it-possible-to-put-just-a-rails-form-element-in-a-partial)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `:remote => true` it makes the button asynchronously(Ajax call).

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Add Journal", new_journal_path, remote: true, class: 'new_journal_button'%>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('.new_journal_button').after("<%= j render('form') %>");
$('.new_journal_button').hide();
```

> If you want to submit a form asynchronously(Ajax call)

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@journal, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "journal" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Journal', autofocus: true, 'data-behavior' => 'submit_on_enter' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Journals_controller.rb**

```
  def index
     @journal = Journal.new
     @journals = Journal.all
  end

  def create
    @journal = Journal.new(journal_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @journal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @journal, notice: 'Journal was successfully created.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was pondering on how to replace part of the form (if that is what you are doing) for a while. The following is not perfect but "works for me".

We instantiate the form builder **f** in the controller (instead of a view) and render only your partial into a string. Then escape and render js into Ajax reply as usually.

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        helpers.form_for(@journal) do |f|
          out = render_to_string partial: 'journal_entry_transaction_fields', locals: {f: f}
          render js: %($('.journal-entry').html("#{helpers.j out}");)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Perhaps the corresponding coffeescript part that is Turbolinks friendly and uses jQuery for sending Ajax is akin to

```
$(document).on 'change', '#something', (e) ->
  $.get
    url: "/path/to/your/controller/#{e.target.value}.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could send `@journal` object then use `fields_for @journal` into partial

**.js.erb**

```js
$('.journal-entry').html("<%= j render partial: 'journal_entry_transaction_fields', object: @journal %>");
```

**Partial** .html.erb

```rb
<%= fields_for @journal do |f| %>
   ... code .....
<% end %>
```